# how to bind angularjs with firestore

Tags: angularjs, google-cloud-firestore

I need to use Angular first version (AngularJS) with google firestore.

Some ideas or examples?

```
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "A###",
  authDomain: "###",
  databaseURL: "###",
  projectId: "###",
  storageBucket: "###",
  messagingSenderId: "###"
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig); 


// --------------------------------------------------- Inizializzo Angular
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["firebase"]);
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

$scope.db = firebase.firestore();
// ^ this give me firestore db, but not binded with angular. I can only work async.
```

Comment: It's not really clear what your question is here.  Please don't use comments for explanations of problems, it is too hard to identify.  Aside from that, what does "not binded with angular" mean?  What *exactly* are you trying to do that isn't working how you expect?

Comment: Sorry i'm new in this forum.
I'm starting to create a new project with ANGULAR JS 1.x
I'm really interest to leave MySql and starting to work with Google NoSql Firstore (Beta).

For now i've found a right way to bind angular 1.x with FIREBASE, ba not FIRSTORE.

Any suggestions? Thank's